# SFML C++ How to color sprites with 12 different colors

Tags: c++, sfml

So, I am trying to create a Warcraft II RTS clone with SFML. I finished my menu now, a menu which should support 12 different player thus 12 different colors, however I have problems with colorizing the different sprites i downloaded from the internet, and probably making 12 different png files to load for each unit/building would be a huge waste of time and memory.

I saw many different suggestions on this topic but they seemed either unpractical or just really really hard to do.

These are some examples of the sprites I got

[image: Footman png]
[image: Team Colors png]

[image]

Also here is the link for the full project (this however doesn't include helpful information about these sprites, because only the menu is done):
https://github.com/lori2001/Warcraft-II---clone/tree/master

Any suggestions are welcome ! :)

Comment: Depends on how picky you are with the results, but you should be able to call `setColor()` on the sprites to tint them. This will mess up skin tones too of course, but might be viable for a first pass. Otherwise might want to separate skin and clothes in two different textures and then only `setColor` of the clothes, leaving the skin intact.

Comment: Thats a good idea, its easy to do that for the footman sprites, however its quite hard for sprites like the ones in EDIT..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second picture you posted indicates the key: the characters are identical except for the four color shades indicated at the bottom.
Thus, you could preprocess your sprite sheets and separate them into the paletted bits and non-paletted bits.

What you do afterwards is up to you; the simplest is probably to generate one new sprite sheet per color and use the correct sprite sheet when rendering a unit for a given color. In OpenGL terms, I would think of a 3D texture where the first dimension is the color.

Alternatively, you could use an RGBA texture and mark the paletted bits using the alpha channel; rendering would then be something along the lines of

```
if (pixel.a == 1.0) {
    outputColor = vec4(pixel.rgb, 1.0);
} else {
    int idx = pixel.r / 0.25;
    outputColor = vec4(palette[idx].rgb, 1.0);
}
```

where `pixel` is the pixel in your sprite sheet, and `palette` is a shader uniform containing four RGB values. An alpha value of 1 would keep the input pixel, while any of [0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75] would use the corresponding palette index.